# Reference request: structure of stabilisers of totally isotropic subspaces in orthogonal (and unitary) groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, lie-groups, orthogonality, classical-groups

I am looking for a book or paper which covers the structure of stabilisers in
$GO(n,F)$, $SO(n,F)$ (or maybe in $\Omega(n,F)$) of totally isotropic subspaces of dimension $k$. Can you please suggest any references? I am also interested in the same questions for unitary groups, but orthogonal groups are my priority at the moment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For finite fields $F$, you will find a very detailed and comprehensive treatment in [the book by Kleidman and Liebeck](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/subgroup-structure-of-the-finite-classical-groups/12A71CAF8DCF91B491C81B2E7F72946B) on the maximal subgroups of the finite classical groups.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know anything about general case?